# Javascript: Merge Objects in array with different key/value pairs, and getitng the sum from the same keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash, reduce

So what I have is an array of objects

```
[
    {
        "email": "jacob@whatever.com",
        "actionsCount": {
            "edit record": 5,
            "assign to specialist": 1
        },
        "changesTotal": 6
    },
    {
        "email": "trav1@whatever.com",
        "actionsCount": {
            "edit record": 13,
            "duplicate": 5,
            "return for changes": 1
        },
        "changesTotal": 19
    },
    {
        "email": "donbossman@whatever.com",
        "actionsCount": {
            "edit record": 5
        },
        "changesTotal": 5
    },
    {
        "email": "donbossman@whatever.com",
        "actionsCount": {
            "edit record": 11,
            "return for changes": 1,
            "assign to specialist": 1
        },
        "changesTotal": 13
    },
    {
        "email": "Marilla@whatever.com",
        "actionsCount": {
            "edit record": 7
        },
        "changesTotal": 7
    },
    {
        "email": "Marilla@whatever.com",
        "actionsCount": {
            "edit record": 6
        },
        "changesTotal": 6
    },
    {
        "email": "natalie1@whatever.com",
        "actionsCount": {
            "edit record": 5,
            "assign to specialist": 1
        },
        "changesTotal": 6
    },
    {
        "email": "natalie1@whatever.com",
        "actionsCount": {
            "assign to specialist": 2,
            "edit record": 17
        },
        "changesTotal": 19
    },
    {
        "email": "psteacher@whatever.com",
        "actionsCount": {
            "edit record": 2,
            "assign to specialist": 2
        },
        "changesTotal": 4
    },
    {
        "email": "psteacher@whatever.com",
        "actionsCount": {
            "edit record": 17,
            "duplicate": 2
        },
        "changesTotal": 19
    }
]
```

As you can see there will be multiple entries under the same email, these correspond to each month that user did some actions, as such new entries will populate each month, some most of them by the same users. I don't know all of the actions, but I can be assured that the actions will all be spelled the same. The data is old so as you can see someone used spaces for the key which is another task for another day.

I want to combine objects by the same email, then sum the same actions across the months, and add actions that are present in one month but not another.

So as an example `donbossman@whatever.com` end result would look like

Would look like

```
[{
  "email": "donbossman@whatever.com",
  "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 16,
      "return for changes": 1,
      "assign to specialist": 1
  }
  "changesTotal": 18
}]
```

So because `edit record` is present in both occurrences of `actionsCount` they are simply added up, and `return for changes` and `assign to specialist` are present in one but not the other

Right now I feel like I'm close to what I'm trying to achieve? My current approach is as follows

```
tier2CollectorsActions.reduce((acc, {email, actionsCount}) => {
          acc[email] ??= {email: email, actionsCount: []};
          if(Array.isArray(actionsCount))
            acc[email].actionsCount = _.merge(acc[email].actionsCount, actionsCount)
          else
            acc[email].actionsCount.push(actionsCount);
          return acc;
        }, {})
```

Which gives me back

```
{
    "email": "natalie1@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": [
        {
            "edit record": 5,
            "assign to specialist": 1
        },
        {
            "assign to specialist": 2,
            "edit record": 17
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see each `actionsCount` array corresponds to the two separate `natalie1@whatever.com` object's `actionsCount` data. I need the actionsCount data back not as an array but an object, I'm doing it as an array in the example bc its so far been the only way I can get the data from both `actionCounts`. I've been trying to use Object.value and reduce but I haven't quite gotten yet but I feel like I'm so close.

Any direction/tips/suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: does `_.merge` know how to sum the values? I don't think so.

Comment: Why are you setting `actionsCount` to an array? You don't want an array in your expected result, it's just an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.

1. Seems like `actionsCount` is always an object, never an array
2. Just add the things to the object

```js
const data = [{
    "email": "jacob@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 5,
      "assign to specialist": 1
    },
    "changesTotal": 6
  },
  {
    "email": "trav1@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 13,
      "duplicate": 5,
      "return for changes": 1
    },
    "changesTotal": 19
  },
  {
    "email": "donbossman@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 5
    },
    "changesTotal": 5
  },
  {
    "email": "donbossman@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 11,
      "return for changes": 1,
      "assign to specialist": 1
    },
    "changesTotal": 13
  },
  {
    "email": "Marilla@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 7
    },
    "changesTotal": 7
  },
  {
    "email": "Marilla@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 6
    },
    "changesTotal": 6
  },
  {
    "email": "natalie1@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 5,
      "assign to specialist": 1
    },
    "changesTotal": 6
  },
  {
    "email": "natalie1@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "assign to specialist": 2,
      "edit record": 17
    },
    "changesTotal": 19
  },
  {
    "email": "psteacher@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 2,
      "assign to specialist": 2
    },
    "changesTotal": 4
  },
  {
    "email": "psteacher@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 17,
      "duplicate": 2
    },
    "changesTotal": 19
  }
]

const result = data.reduce((acc, {
  email,
  actionsCount,
  changesTotal
}) => {
  acc[email] ??= {
    email: email,
    actionsCount: {},
    changesTotal: 0
  };
  Object.entries(actionsCount).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    acc[email].actionsCount[key] ??= 0
    acc[email].actionsCount[key] += value
  })
  acc[email].changesTotal += changesTotal
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Wow I feel utterly dumb I sat here for an embarrasing amount of time wondering why it wasn't working. I tried Object.value/map combo earlier but couldn't connect the dots. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use lodash's `_.groupBy()` to group the items by email, and then map the groups and merge them using `_.mergeWith()`. In the customizer function of `_.mergeWith()` check if either of the values is a number (since one of them might be `undefined`), and if they are numbers sum them. If not, let `_.mergeWith()` handle them by return `undefined`:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, map, mergeWith, isNumber } = _

const fn = flow(
  arr => groupBy(arr, 'email'),
  groups => map(groups, items => mergeWith(...items, (o1, o2) =>
    isNumber(o1) || isNumber(o2) ? (o1 ?? 0) + (o2 ?? 0) : undefined 
  ))
)

const arr = [{"email":"jacob@whatever.com","actionsCount":{"edit record":5,"assign to specialist":1},"changesTotal":6},{"email":"trav1@whatever.com","actionsCount":{"edit record":13,"duplicate":5,"return for changes":1},"changesTotal":19},{"email":"donbossman@whatever.com","actionsCount":{"edit record":5},"changesTotal":5},{"email":"donbossman@whatever.com","actionsCount":{"edit record":11,"return for changes":1,"assign to specialist":1},"changesTotal":13},{"email":"Marilla@whatever.com","actionsCount":{"edit record":7},"changesTotal":7},{"email":"Marilla@whatever.com","actionsCount":{"edit record":6},"changesTotal":6},{"email":"natalie1@whatever.com","actionsCount":{"edit record":5,"assign to specialist":1},"changesTotal":6},{"email":"natalie1@whatever.com","actionsCount":{"assign to specialist":2,"edit record":17},"changesTotal":19},{"email":"psteacher@whatever.com","actionsCount":{"edit record":2,"assign to specialist":2},"changesTotal":4},{"email":"psteacher@whatever.com","actionsCount":{"edit record":17,"duplicate":2},"changesTotal":19}]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Ah I was looking into lodash's _.mergeWith function, so thank you for demonstrating it's usage. I've been getting more into using lodash (wasn't something I particularly used much, but I see it's immense value). If I'm understanding _.mergeWith correctly, it's like `_.merge` but you can create a function that it will utilise?

Comment: You can add a customizer function to control the merge between two values.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll need to mess with lodash more, it's been proving to be an amazing library. Not sure how I've gone this long without it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't initialize `actionsCount` to an array. That's causing it to push each `actionsCount` object onto the array, instead of combining the properties.

You need to loop over the properties in `actionsCount`, adding them to the corresponding value in `acc[email]`.

```js
const tier2CollectorsActions = [{
    "email": "jacob@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 5,
      "assign to specialist": 1
    },
    "changesTotal": 6
  },
  {
    "email": "trav1@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 13,
      "duplicate": 5,
      "return for changes": 1
    },
    "changesTotal": 19
  },
  {
    "email": "donbossman@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 5
    },
    "changesTotal": 5
  },
  {
    "email": "donbossman@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 11,
      "return for changes": 1,
      "assign to specialist": 1
    },
    "changesTotal": 13
  },
  {
    "email": "Marilla@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 7
    },
    "changesTotal": 7
  },
  {
    "email": "Marilla@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 6
    },
    "changesTotal": 6
  },
  {
    "email": "natalie1@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 5,
      "assign to specialist": 1
    },
    "changesTotal": 6
  },
  {
    "email": "natalie1@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "assign to specialist": 2,
      "edit record": 17
    },
    "changesTotal": 19
  },
  {
    "email": "psteacher@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 2,
      "assign to specialist": 2
    },
    "changesTotal": 4
  },
  {
    "email": "psteacher@whatever.com",
    "actionsCount": {
      "edit record": 17,
      "duplicate": 2
    },
    "changesTotal": 19
  }
];

const result = tier2CollectorsActions.reduce((acc, {
  email,
  actionsCount
}) => {
  acc[email] ??= {
    email: email,
    actionsCount: {}
  };
  Object.entries(actionsCount).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    acc[email].actionsCount[key] = (acc[email].actionsCount[key] || 0) + value;
  });
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```